# mpirun takes too long to run

Tags: macos, openmpi

After upgrading my Mac to El Capitan and reinstalling Open MPI using brew, it seems, even for the simplest MPI C++ programs, that `mpirun` just takes too long to run.

Am I the only one having this issue? I am very frustrated about all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I just changed my MPI implementation as follows

```
brew uninstall open-mpi
brew install mpich
```